# Sitecore 7.2 web_index doesn't get updated

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

We are using Sitecore 7.2 out of box lucene indexing implementation. Both CD and CA lives on same server under same app pool.

And the indexing strategy used is out of box:

```xml
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
```

Recently we restored the production Master and Web database to System Test environment, since then the web_index doesn't get updated i.e everytime I publish the item it doesn't appear in search. I made sure that it's actually published to Web DB.

However, if I switch the Web DB to Master DB on  configuration it works as it happens that master_index get updated every time item is published. I confirmed this by looking at the  folder date time for both sitecore_web_index and sitecore_master_index, where only sitecore_master_index is updated but not web one.

I also, deleted everything under Indexes folder and Rebuilt the Full index via Developer Tab on Content Editor. It successfully built both master and web indexes. The missing item appeared on search. BUT again, when I create new item and publish it doesn't appear on search.

I suspect that for some weird reason, the onPublishEndSync is not getting fired for Web_index. I'm not sure why. I also truncated the History and Event Queue table on Web DB.

Could someone please help me out what could be the culprit.

Comment: I've seen this behavior after we did a database restore the databases except core! Check out this post http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=62915 I added some details there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post whether you're trying to run the strategy on the **authoring** instance or the **delivery** instance.

Assuming it's the delivery instance, first make sure that

- The EnableEventQueues setting is set to true
- The EventQueue table within the database has entries dated later than index’s last update timestamp